# Php [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Tags: php, directive

I am having problem with my php code. Directory and its code is working fine when direct accessing

For example subdomain.domain.com/folder_name_c/index.php?id=1

but when I use header() function to redirect to that directory it generates error. [an error occurred while processing this directive]

Here is the code that I am using.

```
if($_POST){

    if($_POST['xyz'] != '' && $_POST['xyz2'] != ''){
        header("Location http://subdomain.domain.com/folder_name_c/index.php?id=".$_POST['comp']."&xyz=".$_POST['xyz']."&xyz2=".$_POST['xyz2']);
    }else if($_POST['month'] != ''){
        header("Location http://subdomain.domain.com/folder_name_c/index.php?id=".$_POST['comp']."&xyz=".$_POST['xyz']);
    }

}
```

Help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is in

```
header("Location: ...
```

you need a colon after Location

Comment: You are right that was the issue. How silly is this. Sometimes little errors put you in deep trouble. Well thanks. :)

Comment: I know the feeling :P